# Is there a working JSLint Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jslint

Can anyone point to a functioning [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) plug-in for Eclipse?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

<del>There is a plugin [here](http://www.rockstarapps.com/joomla-1.5.8/products/jslint-eclipse-plugin.html) and it works ok. (site is down sometime in 2011)</del> 
<del>The update site is http://update.rockstarapps.com/site.xml</del> (site down 2012-07-24)

You can also run [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/) as an external tool:

1. Download [jslint4java](http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/downloads/list)
2. Put `jslint4java.jar` somewhere
3. Add an external tool configuration in Eclipse (Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations > Program > New...):

   ```
   Location: /usr/bin/java
             (or your path to javaw.exe)
   Arguments: -jar /path/to/jslint4java.jar ${resource_loc}
   ```

Now you can select a js file in the Project Explorer and run jslint4java from the external tools menu.

Comment: You might find jslint4java to be easier to integrate.  It's just a "java -jar" command.  http://code.google.com/p/jslint4java/

Comment: I _just_ installed the RockStarApps plug-in a few days ago. Went to install on a different laptop and the domain's expired.

Comment: The rockstarapps.com update site is not working anymore. Looks like the whole domain is gone and up for sale actually.

Comment: @garbelini Likely needs an update. It used the same engine and matched the online tool's output when it was done in 2011.

Answer (score 43):

Use this:

In Eclipse, Install New Software to http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

I used [jslint4java](https://github.com/happygiraffe/jslint4java) to add jslint to the [Eclipse plugin](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/) for Android PhoneGap development. If you're not interested in PhoneGap or Android, you can choose only the jslint4java feature in the install wizard

Usage information [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/announce-1/mds12released-nowwithjslintjshint).

Comment: this answer is undervoted, installing jsLint plugin takes just a minute with this approach

Comment: To enable jslint in your project you must right click on the open project and click on 'Enable jslint4java'.

Comment: seems a little buggy, it happily ignores all kinds of problems which the online jslint tool picks up. configured max strictness via preferences, creates a file containing simply 'a=1;' online jslint shows 3 errors but the eclipse plugin shows none

Comment: http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download, isnt active anymore, does anyone know of an alternative repo that we can download the plugin from? Tnx Tom

Comment: It's still available on the Eclipse Marketplace - https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/applaud-phonegap-android-jslintjshint.  The source is available at https://github.com/paulb777/android-eclipse-plugin-for-phonegap. However, I can provide no assurance about compatibility with recent Eclipse platform releases.

Comment: Paul, I installed the plugin from the marketplace, but now I cant seem to find it anywhere in Eclipse. There no sign of jslint installed anywhere? Tnx Tom

Comment: It may need changes to work with anything after Eclipse Juno (2012)

Answer (score 28):

I think I've found the simplest solution. If you install [Aptana Studio](https://github.com/aptana/studio3), a free Eclipse plug-in, you get among other things, an excellent JavaScript IDE with support for Ext, jQuery and other major libraries.

[Using these instructions](http://nicolaasmatthijs.blogspot.com/2009/05/enabling-jslint-in-aptana-studio.html) (copied here in case blogspot is blocked at work), you can easily turn on JSLint support.

> You can enable it by doing:
>
> 1. Open Aptana Studio- Go to Window > Preferences
> 2. Go to Aptana > Editors > JavaScript > Validation in the left hand menu
> 3. Check "JSLint JavaScript Validator"- Hit OK- Go to Window > Show View > Validation
>      (may need to go to Show View - Other - Aptana Views)
> 4. You'll see the Validation on the bottom right of the screen- Now also click Toggle Information and Toggle Warnings (found on the top left corner of the validation pane)
>
> You're all set. JSLint will warn you whilst writing code

Comment: For people using Aptana Studio 3, JavaScript validation hasn't been implemented yet but they say it's planned for the final version. https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/questions/680-javascript-validation-in-aptana-3

Comment: It's actually in Preferences > Aptana > Validation > JavaScript
  .  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Gabriel It really depends on your version of Eclipse and your version of Aptana. I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2.r362 & Aptana 2.0.5 and the path I listed is valid for those versions.

Comment: This is no longer working as expected with Eclipse 3.7

The plug-in installs correctly, but the options are not present anywhere in the UI. Not in the project settings, not in the project contextual menu and not in the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: Gabriel are you sure you're looking in the right place?  I'm running 3.7(.2v20120207...) and I have the options under Aptana Studio>Validation (and then on the right-hand side, "Javascript").

Comment: I believe this comment is underrated - having installed both jslint4java and  the Aptana Studio eclipse plugins, I've found the Aptana eclipse plugin to be much more robust and flexible. For example, after being properly configured to ignore warnings in frameworks, it doesnt throw errors in selectors unlike jslint4java - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project for steps to ignore errors in library files.

Answer (score 20):

You might consider a JsHint Eclipse plugin as an alternative.
From what the project objective reads, JSHint was originally a fork of JsLHint with more option configuration.

Eclipse plugin http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/

JsHint reference http://www.jshint.com/about/

Comment: Of note also, you can provide a jslint.js file in the plugins configuration in order to use the latest jslint instead of the default bundled.

Comment: Just for reference, I made a fork of the jshint plugin after they decided it should only work for jshint.js. Check it out here https://github.com/Weightpoint/jslint-eclipse

Comment: Does not seem to work with Eclipse Photon: An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.javascript, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]com.eclipsesource.jshint 0.10.1.20160216-0911, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.InstallBundleAction).
Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.
Could not acquire the framework manipulator service.

Answer (score 6):

I do this a different way that integrates nicely with the IDE In eclipse most of this is one time set up and then it becomes quite easy to validate your code after that.

1. Help -> Install new software
2. Click the 'Add' button

   - Name : Rockstar Apps (or whatever you want)
   - Location : http://update.rockstarapps.com/site.xml
3. expend the selection and check Rockstar JsLint
4. Click 'Next'...again
5. Accept and install

   - (you'll have to hit okay when it prompts you about installing unsigned content).
6. Restart Eclipse...

Almost done

Now when you want to validate your javascript right click the file Rockstarapps -> Validate with JsLint...

customize your validation settings and your done. (i usually just choose recommended)
the problems will show up in your problems panel.

Comment: do you need to be in a certain view for this to work? I can see it's installed but can't find any way to run it from the application...

Comment: It seems the Rockstar Repo site has been pwned.

Comment: Anyone know who the original RockStarApps developer was? Seems like this would have found a new home *somewhere*.

Comment: @artlung a while back i read "jslint is dead" its been replaced by jshint which can be found here [link](http://github.eclipsesource.com/jshint-eclipse/)

Comment: This domain no longer exists http://update.rockstarapps.com/