# How do you clear the validation errors in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally clicked on "Validate" for all of my projects (instead of going to Team > synchronize...) and I have several validation errors and tons of warnings.

I can't figure out how to clear these so it goes back to just having the standard errors.

(One way is to go to "Configure Contents" of the "Problems" view and deselect the validation errors, but I know they're still there, just hidden... it bugs me that they're not actually removed)

I've tried restarting eclipse, tried cleaning all projects but that doesn't clear these validation errors.

Answer (score 117):

You should be able to select all the offending markers in the Problems View, right-click and choose `Delete` from the context menu. Clean-building causes all builders to remove only the markers that they produced, but these markers weren't produced by a builder (you created them through an explicit invocation of the "validate" command.)

Comment: The only problem I can see here is having to delete all errors , (in my case a 100 at a time).

Comment: @Pradyot: Deleting the markers file as takteek noted, does the trick for all entries at once.

Comment: For me, most of the time this advice isn't relevant.  I usually want to clear markers that _don't_ show up in the problems view.  (As in bug in Eclipse plugins, not markers hidden by design.)

Comment: Hours of frustration ended with this answer.  Thank you.  @Pradyot you can delete the parent item to remove an entire group.

Comment: I didn't realize it was possible to just 'delete' an error from Eclipse.  Didn't even think to try.  Fixing bugs just got 1000x faster.

Comment: @aroth Now there just needs to be a builder which removes them automatically whenever they're created, and we'll have no more bugs forever!

Answer (score 18):

I'm not aware of a built-in way to clear them all. You might try deleting the markers file in

```
[workspace dir]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/[project name]
```

Comment: That could delete a lot more than problem markers... better to do `rm [workspace dir]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/*/org.eclipse.jdt.core/state.dat` ... even then, I don't know what other metadata might be in the state.dat file besides resource markers.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Window -> Show View -> Problems and delete error marker(s) on right mouse-click

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to exclude some third party libraries (such as jquery-1.x.min.js) from being validated by your project.

In this answer I've documented how to disable it for specific sources -> [How do I remove javascript validation from my eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project/7931839#7931839)

I'll just repeat the steps here:

1. Right click your project
2. Select Properties -> JavaScript -> Include
3. Path Select `Source` tab. ( It looks identical to Java Build Path Source tab )
4. Expand JavaScript source folder
5. Highlight `Excluded` pattern
6. Click `Edit` button
7. Click `Add` button next to `Exclusion patterns` box.
8. You may either type Ant-style wildcard pattern, or click `Browse` button to mention the JavaScript source by name.

BTW, I think you should never disable validation for sources that you are in control of (i.e. coded by yourself or your team).

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem but i am able to remove these errors.

1. Go to project properties -> validations and click on override validation preferences.
2. Click on disable all and Apply changes and click on okay. Let the project built.
3. Again go to project properties and change the validation settings as of original.

Answer (score 4):

In case you select and delete more than 100 problems and eclipse only deletes up to 100 problems, check the "Configuration  Contents..." menu. This menu is the top-right of the problems tab. There is a small triangle drop down menu containing the configuration. In that menu, there is a "Use limits" checkbox which you should uncheck to be able to dleete all problems at once.

Answer (score 3):

In Indogo

GO to

`Property -> Builder - > Uncheck Validator`

Answer (score 2):

To disable validators in your project or workspace, complete the following steps:

1. Click Window--> Preferences and select Validation in the left pane. The Validation page of the Preferences window lists the validators available in your project and their settings.
2. To disable individual validators, clear the check boxes next to each validator that you want to disable. Each validator has a check box to specify whether it is enabled for manual validation or on a build.
3. Optional: You can also change the following check box options on this page:

   - Allow projects to override these preference settings--->Select to
     set    individual validation settings for one or more of your
     projects.
   - Suspend all validators-->Select to prevent validation
     at the global    level. If you select this check box, you can still
     enable validation    at the project level.

Then Click OK.

If you want to set individual validation settings for one or more of your projects, see Overriding global validation preferences