# Eclipse removing errors from not compiling code

Tags: java, eclipse, view, compiler-errors

I have some code that does not compile (you have to execute from console to make it compile). However I would like to use it in debug. this works great when I have like 100 errors then I can just delete them from Errors View. However when there is like 60 000 Errors in Error Console this is not possible.

How to remove 60 000 Errors from Error View or make Eclipse not show errors in Error View?

Comment: You can restrict the number of errors shown in a variety of ways; use the `Filter` menu from the view. Or you could just set up your project right.

Comment: Is this question helpful? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420536/how-do-you-clear-the-validation-errors-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should fix your project setup to make the code compile within Eclipse.

Regarding the visibility of items in the error view, you can play around with the filters (button with arrows on the top right) to control which errors are shown.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to filter the error view; click the downarrow on the right and configure contents. Then select select the scope on the right hand side of the dialog. I often find it useful to limit the scope to the selected element and children, but in your case it might be useful to set it more explicitly.

Another possible solution would be to have all that requires processing be in a separate project (and not in a source folder), which produces an output that you can depend on (such as a jar file).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about viewing complilation errors, you could just close the problem tab completely.

Or take out all the code that does not complile - compile it externally into a jar, and include the jar in the project.

Comment: I think he cares about compilation errors, just not in code he knows specifically won't compile unless executed/compiled in some special way.