# What does validate do in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

If you right click the project, and click validate, it'll pop something up and then tons of errors show for some reason. What does validate do and how do you get rid of these errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you clear the validation errors in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420536/how-do-you-clear-the-validation-errors-in-eclipse).

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjvalmanual.html

Comment: Clearly, it created the Error messages in your Problems/Markers View. Are you asking how to get rid of them, as in they're incorrect messages, or how to actually fix your code?

Answer (score 14):

Quoting from [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjval.html) docs:

> The workbench includes validators that check certain files in your enterprise application module projects for errors.
> By default, the workbench validates your files automatically after any build, including automatic builds. You can also begin the validation process manually without building.
>
> On the workbench Preferences window, you can enable or disable validators to be used on your projects. Also, you can enable or disable validators for each enterprise application module project individually on the Properties page for that project.
>
> Each validator can apply to certain types of files, certain project natures, and certain project facets. When a validator applies to a project facet or nature, the workbench uses that validator only on projects that have that facet or nature. Likewise, most validators apply only to certain types of files, so the workbench uses those validators only on those types of files.

For more information please visit [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftjvalmanual.html) page.