# Progress developer studio - ignore error checking include files

Tags: eclipse, progress-4gl, openedge

In Progress Developer Studio (Eclipse):

How do you set up the project so it won't "compile" (check for errors) in .i (include) files separately?

Now we get a lot of errors because include files can not be run on its own. For example some variables that are used in the .i file are defined in p/w file - that will generate an error.

Comment: Are the includes always named .i and what does it look like under Project Properties -> Progress OpenEdge -> Build -> Configure Workspace settings? (Should be something like "Compilable extensions: p,w,cls,pgen,html,htm")

Comment: Yea the includes are always named .i and they are not listed in that list.

Comment: Is it a Build that generates the errors or a single "Source -> Compile" of a separate .i-file? The latter would be expected behavior since the include itself isn't complete and thus cannot compile.

Comment: When using Build All/Clean Build.

Comment: 11.3. Might be this? http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000048421

Comment: The w/p file has errors so the i file do too? Nah thats not it, at least not for all files.

Might be old errors that will not be removed. If I do a Clean (but no build) I still get 28 errors (and with a full build 40 errors).

Comment: Figured out how to remove those errors
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420536/how-do-you-clear-the-validation-errors-in-eclipse
Looks better now. Still errors, but less in .i files. This might have "solved" my question. But will check some more first.

Answer (score 0):

By default includes are not compiled. The errors shown on include files are caused by other sources (.cls, .p, .w) that failed to compile on that include.

See also : [knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000048421](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000048421)