# jQuery Mobile 1.1.0.min Triggers Errors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jquery-mobile

I have a Java servlet project in Eclipse that includes the use of jQuery Mobile 1.1.0.min.  Eclipse scans this file looking for JavaScript errors and it seems to find two such errors.  The Eclipse error list shows:

"Internal Validation error on the 1st character of the file (the "/")

The default case is already defined on "default" in

```
switch(e) {
    case ".":break;
    case "..":
        c.length&&c.pop();
        break;
    default:
        c.push(e)
}
```

No errors occur with the "non-minified" version.  The servlet runs OK and jQM appears to function correctly so I am wondering if these errors might be wrong.  Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to eliminate the error messages?  The hassle is that Eclipse is constantly scanning for errors in the background, which is what we want, but it's constantly popping up a dialog box about these two errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To exclude files do : **Project Properties > JavaScript > Include Path > Source**, there is **"Excluded"** to highlight and press "Edit" button, here you are able to add what you want to exclude (file, folder, pattern). More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867885/how-to-exclude-a-javascript-file-from-javascript-validation-in-eclipse).

I recently created a small test case and filed a [bug against Eclipse JSDT](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376809). Please vote for it.

I put a [hack](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/detail?r=159) into the JSDT that I bundle with the [MDS AppLaud Eclipse plugin for Android](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/) PhoneGap so that JSDT exceptions are ignored.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for this suggestion.  That works but I'm wondering if doing this would exclude it "from the Project" so it wouldn't be included in a WAR Export.  Any idea about that?  I'll go vote if I can figure out how to do so!

Comment: The issue seams to be fixed, is the patched version needed? @Paul?

Comment: Only if you are stuck on an old JSDT

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. I tried using jQuery Mobile 1.0.1.

The problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Switch-Case block with

```
if(d === ".."){
  if ( absStack.length ) {
    absStack.pop();
  }
}
else if(d === "."){

}
else{
    absStack.push( d );
}
```