# Error in Handlebar.js while using ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have downloaded startpack from emberjs.com, it contains 3 js files:

1. ember-1.0.0-rc.5
2. handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4
3. jquery-1.9.1

I created a dynamic web project in eclipse and pasted this js file in WebContents/views/js/lib folder under project.

I am getting an error in handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4.js file at line:

```
lexer.rules = [/^(?:\\\\(?=(\{\{)))/,/^(?:[^\x00]*?(?=(\{\{)))/,/^(?:[^\x00]+)/,/^(?:[^\x00]{2,}?(?=(\{\{|$)))/,/^(?:[\s\S]*?--\}\})/,/^(?:\{\{>)/,/^(?:\{\{#)/,/^(?:\{\{\/)/,/^(?:\{\{\^)/,/^(?:\{\{\s*else\b)/,/^(?:\{\{\{)/,/^(?:\{\{&)/,/^(?:\{\{!--)/,/^(?:\{\{![\s\S]*?\}\})/,/^(?:\{\{)/,/^(?:=)/,/^(?:\.(?=[}/ ]))/,/^(?:\.\.)/,/^(?:[\/.])/,/^(?:\s+)/,/^(?:\}\}\})/,/^(?:\}\})/,/^(?:"(\\["]|[^"])*")/,/^(?:'(\\[']|[^'])*')/,/^(?:@[a-zA-Z]+)/,/^(?:true(?=[}\s]))/,/^(?:false(?=[}\s]))/,/^(?:-?[0-9]+(?=[}\s]))/,/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_$:\-]+(?=[=}\s\/.]))/,/^(?:\[[^\]]*\])/,/^(?:.)/,/^(?:\s+)/,/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_$\-\/]+)/,/^(?:$)/];
```

Syntex error token "," delete this token
Syntex error token ")" delete this token
Syntex error token "]" delete this token

Kindly help me.

Comment: is the order you showed in your question also the order in which you are loading the js files?

Comment: @intuitivepixel: yes... that is the order

Comment: did it work out using the order I mentioned?

Comment: Nope, It didn't work. :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you have 3rd party js libraries that gives errors 
exclude them from the eclipse validation

[How to exclude a Javascript file from Javascript Validation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867885/how-to-exclude-a-javascript-file-from-javascript-validation-in-eclipse)

this way you keep all error validation on your code, but can exclude on jquery handlebars etc

and makes you built the app

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is then the order in which you are loading the js files, try to change it to:

1. jquery-1.9.1
2. handlebars-1.0.0-rc.4
3. ember-1.0.0-rc.5
4. *your app.js etc...*

Please see here a working [example](http://jsbin.com/ewolap/2/edit) with the order showed above.

Hope it helps

Comment: I dont feel there is a problem realted to order. It is a syntax error in handlebar.js, not a runtime error.

Comment: before listen to what you 'feel' have you tried changing the order first?