# error in jquerymobile js file eclipse

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to create a phonegap project using mds aplusdu plugin on eclipse.
but the problem is that I can't run my application because of an error in these files

> jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js
>
> jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js

I tried to download another edition of this js files but I faced the same error.

I tried to Uncheck "Enable JavaScript semantic validation" but it doesn't work.

```
   switch ( d ) {
                    case ".":
                        break;
                    case "..":
                        if ( absStack.length ) {
                            absStack.pop();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:  //here is the error
                        absStack.push( d );
                        break;
                }
```

the error is :

> The default case is already defined

Answer (score 0):

[How to exclude a Javascript file from Javascript Validation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867885/how-to-exclude-a-javascript-file-from-javascript-validation-in-eclipse) - Check for Solution. I hope you can get solution. Repeated Question