# Kendo UI Complete (Trial) and Eclipse Juno: kendo.web.min.js JavaScript Validation Error

Tags: javascript, eclipse, kendo-ui

I just downloaded the trial of Kendo UI Complete. In Eclipse Juno I created a Dynamic Web Project and then copied the js and style directories from the Kendo download into the project's WebContent directory. Eclipse's Problems view reports two JavaScript validation errors, both with kendo.web.min.js:

Syntax error on token "}", delete this token.  (line 1)

Syntax error on token "Invalid Regular Expression Options", no accurate correction available (line 9)

Has anyone else encountered this? What is the fix? Since this is a commercial product, I'm not keen on having to modify the source code just to get it to validate.

Comment: You may need to set up Eclipse to ignore the Kendo files.  See [http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-mobile/application/eclipse-min-js-files-multiple-syntax-errors.aspx](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-mobile/application/eclipse-min-js-files-multiple-syntax-errors.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is notorious for trying to validate minified JavaScript files. It is highly recommended that you disable such validation as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project) answer