# Enable javascript validation for eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

First: I searched a lot and I can't find anyone to have this problem (it seems like it something basic, but I have been 2 hours dealing with this).

My problem is that long ago I had the javascript validator for eclipse. I don't know why I don't have it anymore, but I want it back.

I found this and tried to do the inverse:
[How do I remove javascript validation from my eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project)

But my problem is that when I click Properties under my project, I can't find the "Javascript" tab.. Why? I think the problem is here, I tried modifying anything else under validators, also under window->Preferences->Javascript or Validtors->Client-side Javascript..

Also I don't have the JavaScript Validator under Builders.

**EDIT:**

This is what I see on my project properties:

[image: This is what I see on my project properties]

This is what I see under validation
[image]

This is what I see under Builders
[image]

Comment: Everything in Eclipse starts with the kind of project you're in, so is it a "JavaScript Project" as Eclipse thinks of them?

Comment: @nitind Didn't know that. It is a maven project but it has javascript on its views.. What should I do?

Comment: In the Project Properties, what do you have in the **Builders** section?

Comment: @E-Riz I see Java Builder, Validation and Maven Project Builder. I uploaded a new screenshot so you can see. Should I add something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the JavaScript "nature" to the project (basically, tell Eclipse to treat it as a JavaScript project). Right-click on the project and choose **Configure** > **Convert to JavaScript Project...**. After doing that you should see a Builder named "JavaScript Validator" and have the **JavaScript** section in the properties.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in the latest version (Neon). I'm unable to see a conversion option, nor is there a builder called "JavaScript Validator" (tried this for both "JavaScript Project" and "Static Web Project')

Comment: @PrahladYeri - see my answer. You might be having the same issue as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what settings I enabled my Eclipse Javascript IDE (Neon) still didn't work.

I switched to an older Eclipse EE IDE (Kepler SP2) and that worked.

Maybe my old Mac OS X 10.7 has some issues with the newer version, or EE is better at compiling javascript than the simple Eclipse Javascript IDE.