# Enable javascript validation in eclipse luna

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

Sometime ago I asked this question:
[Enable javascript validation for eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067186/enable-javascript-validation-for-eclipse)

I wanted eclipse to highlight javascript errors/warnings.. The problem as you can see in the answer was that the project was not configured as Javascript Nature. Now I migrated to Eclipse Luna and have the same problem.. But now I cannot find anywhere the option to configure the project. Is there any other way?

[image: Project properties]

Comment: Which package of luna are you using? (Means: Java EE Developers, for Java Developers or etc..)

Comment: Eclipse for Java Developers: `Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600` Does this have something to do with the javascript validation?

Comment: Download "Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers" and try Configure -> Convert to JavaScript Project... . Tell me if this option is still missing. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunasr1a

Answer (score 4):

To add JavaScript perspective to your project follow the steps below.

1. Either right-click on the project and choose "Properties" or go to the top of Eclipse and select "Project Properties" from the menu.
2. Choose "Project Facets" from the tree on the left.
3. Click on "Convert to faceted form" link
4. Check the "JavaScript" check-box and and hit "OK" to close the dialog.

[image]

Comment: I don't see Project facets in the tree of the project properties windows. I've searched a little and could not find anything specific. Do you know why might this happen?

Comment: Make sure you are looking at *"Project Properties"* and not *"Window Preferences"*.

Comment: It doesn't appear.. Maybe it's because it is a Maven project? I uploaded a screenshot to my post.

Comment: Did you download the *"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"*. If you did not install JEE, then you can get it from the Eclipse Marketplace. [Linux 32-bit](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1a/eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-linux-gtk.tar.gz) and [Linux 64-bit](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1a/eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz). Also see: [Maven (Java EE) Integration for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/maven-java-ee-integration-eclipse-wtp-luna)

Comment: Yes I have it. Actually I checked it and have an update to a new version but it neither appeared after updating.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers != eclipse for Java **EE** Developers. Are you sure you have it?

Comment: If you do not see "Project Facets" menu, rigth-click on project, select configure and "Convert to Faceted Form..."

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to enable/disable validators in your project or workspace:**

- Click **Window** > **Preferences** and select **Validation** in the
  left pane. The Validation page of the Preferences window lists the
  validators available in your project and their settings.
- To enable individual validators, clear the check boxes next to each
  validator that you want to enable. Each validator has a check box to 
  specify whether it is enabled for manual validation or on a build.
- Click OK.

Also there is an alternative solution available. Do check [**this**](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/01/26/javascript-validation-with-jshint-eclipse/) out.