# Eclipse shows error if variable declare in .js file by let

Tags: javascript, eclipse-luna

I am using eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0), but it throw's an error when i declare varibale in .js file by let but fine with var

```
let x =10; it throw's an error
```

> syntax error on token

but `var x = 10;` is fine.

Comment: Have you tried updating eclipse?  'let' in JavaScript is quite new...try https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/

Answer (score 0):

are you using the  "use strict" ?

Also are you removing the eclipse validations?

Comment: also,  if you would not like to remove the validations.

Go to this post and check the javascript validator in luna

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826876/enable-javascript-validation-in-eclipse-luna

Comment: Yes i am using "use strict" and one more thing there are lot more validators which one should i removed?

Comment: Also

Right click your project
Select Properties -> JavaScript -> Include
Select Source tab (It looks similar to the Java Build Path Source tab)
Expand source folder
Highlight Excluded pattern
Click Edit button
Click Add button next to Exclusion patterns box.
Click Browse button and select the JavaScript source by name.

Comment: Inside JavaScript no (Include Select Source tab) , present tabs are 1. Code Style 2.Editor 3. Validator