# Undefined CSS/JavaScript/Image file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bower, filepath

I'm developing a web project in Eclipse and using a [bower](http://bower.io/). Some of libraries which I used has demo files and its own dependencies which related to structure of project which is different from structure of my project. Eclipse complains and gives me a lot of errors:

[image]

How can I disable validation of included resources in these folders? I already disabled JavaScript validation on these folder as described here: [How do I remove javascript validation from my eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131878/how-do-i-remove-javascript-validation-from-my-eclipse-project)

Thank you.

Comment: What `Type` of problem are they as shown in this view?

Comment: @nitind, you mean when I open a file in an editor? If yes it shows that path to required file is wrong and shows red error marker.

Comment: No, I assume that screenshot was cropped from the Problems or Markers View in the workbench. The value in the *Type* column can be a clue as to where you have to go to shut them off.

Comment: There's written `Web Resource Problem` in the `Type` column of `Problems` view, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the `Web Resources` preference page for options when it comes to validation. It's provided from https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources .

Comment: Thank you, I've changed settings that it will raise warning instead of error, but it will be great if I could exclude some folders from validation path in future.

Comment: To add this config will be under Preferences / Web / Web Resources.