# Why I cannot use JSLint eclipse plugin by Rockstartapps?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nullpointerexception, jslint

I am running eclipse (Eclipse for PHP Developers).
After installing **JSLint** plugin from Rockstartapps (http://update.rockstarapps.com), the plugin don't validate.

When I am trying to apply validation to particular file (*Right click on the file -> Rockstarapps -> Validate with JSLint...*) it does absolutely nothing.
When saving a file it throws eclipse error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Rockstarapps JsLint Builder' on project 'testapp'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any clue why this happens?

### Update

Found a very good [replacement solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5124470/309031). Works completely the same as plugin by Rockstarapps worked before, perhaps rules are even a bit updated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in that plug-in.